# From long to wide pivot in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have the following dataset Data in Python:

```
            Fac  y
Date        
2017-06-19  A   0.350
2017-06-20  A   1.220
2017-06-21  A   8.730
2017-06-22  A   9.340
2017-06-23  A   4.300
... ... ...
2022-01-25  Z   3.144
2022-01-26  Z   2.278
2022-01-27  Z   1.352
2022-01-28  Z   0.312
2022-01-31  Z   0.312
```

and I want to pivot them from long to wider that it's column to have the name of it's Fac category and to contain the values of y corresponding to each category.

I tried :

```
df = pd.pivot(Data, index='Date', columns='Fac', values='y')
```

but doesn't work.Any help ?

Comment: Please also show your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code

```
df = pd.pivot(Data.reset_index(), index='Date', columns='Fat', values='y')
```

Comment: it doesn't work. I want the column names to the Fac names

Comment: @HungryHomer check the update , reset_index

Comment: I have a Date column as Index. It has duplicate values and so it does not work. Any work around?

Answer (score 1):

Use `pivot_table`:

```
df = pd.pivot_table(Data, 'y', Data.index, 'Fac')
print(df)

# Output
Fac            A      Z
Date                   
2017-06-19  0.35    NaN
2017-06-20  1.22    NaN
2017-06-21  8.73    NaN
2017-06-22  9.34    NaN
2017-06-23  4.30    NaN
2022-01-25   NaN  3.144
2022-01-26   NaN  2.278
2022-01-27   NaN  1.352
2022-01-28   NaN  0.312
2022-01-31   NaN  0.312
```

You can also use `fill_value=0` as parameter of `pivot_table` to replace `NaN` by 0:

```
df = pd.pivot_table(Data, 'y', Data.index, 'Fac', fill_value=0)
print(df)

# Output
Fac            A      Z
Date                   
2017-06-19  0.35  0.000
2017-06-20  1.22  0.000
2017-06-21  8.73  0.000
2017-06-22  9.34  0.000
2017-06-23  4.30  0.000
2022-01-25  0.00  3.144
2022-01-26  0.00  2.278
2022-01-27  0.00  1.352
2022-01-28  0.00  0.312
2022-01-31  0.00  0.312
```

**Note**: if you have multiple values for a same `(Date, Fac)`, use `aggfunc` parameter to apply an operation to the duplicate values: `mean`, `first`, `last`, `max`, `min`, `sum` or a custom function.

For example, use the first value found:

```
df = pd.pivot_table(Data, 'y', Data.index, 'Fac', fill_value=0, aggfunc='first')
print(df)

# Output (doesn't change here because you have only unique (Date, Fac)
Fac            A      Z
Date                   
2017-06-19  0.35  0.000
2017-06-20  1.22  0.000
2017-06-21  8.73  0.000
2017-06-22  9.34  0.000
2017-06-23  4.30  0.000
2022-01-25  0.00  3.144
2022-01-26  0.00  2.278
2022-01-27  0.00  1.352
2022-01-28  0.00  0.312
2022-01-31  0.00  0.312
```

Comment: I have a Date column with repeating values. And this does not work. Is there any work around?

Comment: @prashanthmanohar. Try `pd.pivot_table(Data, 'y', [Data.index, Data.groupby(level='Date').cumcount()], 'Fac', fill_value=0, aggfunc='first')`